# Using Entity Framework -Is there a way to pass a string of commands to be executed in a manner similar to a stored procedure?

Tags: entity-framework

I want something that achieves a simmilar effect to passing the text of a stored proc to SQL Server and then executing it?

For example to set identity_insert and then insert a value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("INSERT INTO....");
```

This can take multiple commands if you wish.

Comment: Maybe. Can you execute multiple sql commands in sequence using that?
i.e to set indentity_insert then to do the insert

Comment: @kirsteng i believe so yes